# How to inherit multiple leaf parts in composite c#?

Tags: c#, composite

I am writing project in c# which includes more then one leaf and I am wondering if those nodes should inherit composite instead of abstract class. So I have three leafs:

1. Paragraph
2. Group of Paragraphs
3. Document

Paragraph inherits text class which is abstract class. Now, Group of Paragraphs class inherits Paragraph class and Document inherits Group of Paragraphs and Paragraphs. So I am wondering which class should be my composite? I was thinking of placing composite in ParagraphComposite.cs class and then making it look like this:

Paragraph and ParagraphComposite inherit abstract class text and Group of Paragraphs and Document inherit ParagraphComposite class.

Is this right approach? Any feedback would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have an issue understanding something: Your Visual Studio Projects have leaves? Leaf is generally relared to a tree data structure, not VS or Programming projects.

Comment: You would want to use Inherits with a "Is a" relationship. You have a class "Dog" and a class "Poodle". Poodle "Is a" dog so the Poodle class can logically Inherit Dog. This looks like mostly "has a" relationship. In a "has a" you might want to have a property in the Group of Paragraphs class as a collection of Paragraphs.

Comment: I am wondering on how to organize inheritance in my c# Composite project. I have three leafs in my project and i am wondering if last two leafs should inherit composite class.

Comment: So what should Group of Paragraph and Document inherit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that all these classes have properties in common, like, as an example, a `Text` property, but also differing properties like collections of other types. To not conflict with the `Text` property, I will call the abstract base class `TextBase`.

The other classes should derive from `TextBase`. E.g. `Document` document would have a `ParagraphGroups` collection, but not a `Paragraphs` collection. I.e., it cannot derive from `ParagraphGroup` which has a `Paragraphs` collection.

Possible approach:

```
public abstract class TextBase
{
    public const string LineSeparator = "\n";
    public const string ParagraphSeparator = "\r";
    public const string ParagraphGroupSeparator = "\v";

    public abstract string Text { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Paragraph : TextBase
{
    public string[] Lines { get; set; } = new string[0];

    public override string Text
    {
        get => String.Join(LineSeparator, Lines);
        set => Lines = value.Split(new string[] { LineSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```

```
public class ParagraphGroup : TextBase
{
    public Paragraph[] Paragraphs { get; set; } = new Paragraph[0];

    public override string Text
    {
        get => String.Join(ParagraphSeparator, Paragraphs.Select(p => p.Text));
        set => Paragraphs =
            value.Split(new string[] { ParagraphSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select(s => new Paragraph { Text = s })
                .ToArray();
    }
}
```

```
public class Document : TextBase
{
    public ParagraphGroup[] ParagraphGroups { get; set; } = new ParagraphGroup[0];

    public override string Text
    {
        get => String.Join(ParagraphGroupSeparator, ParagraphGroups.Select(g => g.Text));
        set => ParagraphGroups =
            value.Split(new string[] { ParagraphGroupSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select(s => new ParagraphGroup { Text = s })
                .ToArray();
    }
}
```

The `Document` class does not inherit `ParagraphGroup`. Instead, it contains a collection of `ParagraphGroup`. I used arrays for sake of simplicity, but you could also use `List<T>` or create your own specific collection types.

Note that when you get or set the `Text` property of the `Document`, this recursively calls the `Text` property of `ParagraphGroup` and `Paragraph`, so that the elements are joined or split recursively.

You would get the first text line in a document with

```
string firstLine = document.ParagraphGroups[0].Paragraphs[0].Lines[0];
```

---

Where do you place methods like `Add` or `Remove`?

One possibility is to simply rely on the corresponding methods of the collections you are using. Example: if you are using `List<T>` collection, you can simply use the [List Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#methods) (example `paragraph.Lines.Add("hello");`.

If you want to add these methods directly to `Document`, `Paragraph` etc, you are facing the problem that some of them will take parameters of different types. You could make `TextBase` generic, but you would lose the assignment compatibility. It is better to declare a generic interface. E.g.

```
public interface ITextCollection<T>
{
    public abstract void Add(T item);
    public abstract void RemoveAt(int i);
}
```

A possible implementation for `Paragraph` (assuming that you are using a `List<string>` for the `Lines` property. `Paragraph` would implement `ITextCollection<string>`

```
public void Add(string item)
{
    Lines.Add(item);
}

public void RemoveAt(int i)
{
    Lines.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Note that the implementation is different for the other types, because they have collections named differently and being of another type. E.g. `ParagraphGroup` would implement `ITextCollection<Paragraph>` and would have to add and remove from the `Paragraphs` collection.

This makes your classes composites in the sense that they do not implement the details of collection functionality themselves, but instead contain a collection and are delegating the operations to these collections.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! So which class is Composite class? I need to add add, remove to list functions etc

Comment: I added the replay to my answer.